# preg_replace remove only the word after @

Tags: preg-replace

I'm trying to remove the username in a string. Tried the code below but it removes everything after the @

```
$string = 'he @username die';
$string = preg_replace('/@.*/','',$string); 
echo $string; // output: he
```

I want the output to be: he die

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\S` that means anything that is not a space character (the opposite of `\s`) instead of `.`:

```
$string = 'he @username die';
$string = preg_replace('/@\S+/','',$string); 
echo $string; // output: he  die
```

You may want to remove also the following space:

```
$string = 'he @username die';
$string = preg_replace('/@\S+\s*/','',$string); 
echo $string; // output: he die
```

Comment: works perfectly! but i don't see any difference between the first and the second. both output is he die. is it because of the php version?

Comment: @ira_: There are 2 spaces betwen `he` and `die` in the first, only1 in the second.